# Android - Google Play - Upload APK

Tags: android

I uploaded my first app to Google Play some weeks back, and everything works fine. However I have an update and need to push it to Google Play. I've done research and found that I needed to add the following to my manifest file:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.shouttag.mothership"
    android:versionCode="2"
    android:versionName="1.1" >
```

However, when I try to upload the signed APK file, I keep getting the dreaded "You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 1." error. Is this because in the first version, I didn't have the `versionCode` or `versionName` attributes?

Any guidance on how I can resolve this sitch?

Comment: No, you can't upload an apk without setting a version code. Maybe you are generating the apk with a default version code. What tool are you using to build the apk?

Comment: When you modify the manifest, if you are working in Eclipse, try doing Clean and Build to update the Binary file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Android Studio, make sure to also change the version in the build.gradle.

Comment: Ok, your solution helped, sort of. Being an android newb, I didn't know where to find the build.gradle. It ended up being under `app`, which is important, because you don't want to edit the file with the same name in root project dir. I was able to change the versionCode and versionName, and successfully uploaded the APK. Question, do I need to have these values in build.gradle && the manifest file, or is build.gradle enough?

Comment: Having those values in the build.gradle should be enough. From my experience, they seem to override the manifest values anyway.